# Is there a way to block all incoming phone calls except in your area code?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-recommendation, call, caller-id

I want to block all incoming calls on my iPhone that are not from my area code so that I will not receive any unsolicited calls from out of state, particularly related to my resume.

I read that one can block phone calls using a range of phone area code to block by adding them to a blacklist. I was wondering if you could do the opposite, block everything except phone numbers that you "whitelist" in an address range.

If iPhone does't allow it, then maybe it exists as a third party option?

Comment: Mobile phones don't have an area code. [At least, not in the UK] They simply have a code that defines them as a 'mobile phone'. Most businesses call from non-geographical numbers too. How are you going to differentiate?

Comment: After some searching, I realized that Apple has a similar feature called "Do Not Disturb"... all you do..is set "Do not disturb" toggle on, then select "always silient", then select "Allow calls from contact", and disable "repeat calls"...after that, nobody can ring your phone unless they are on your contacts list... you still have to deal with your phone voicemailbox filling up with spam however... not unless there's a way to disable voice message box entirely??? my friends can send text messages...

Comment: Firewall is an app that will only allow whitelisted numbers through, it is not free and I have seen reports from some users that they have had issues with disabling it once enabled. I have been using it for a couple of months and really like it.